# Issues with installing Hive on Ubuntu: $HADOOP_HOME or $HADOOP_PREFIX must be set or hadoop must be in the

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, installation, hive

I have installed Hadoop on my Ubuntu EC2 instance and have gone through all the steps for installing hive following this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hive/hive_installation.htm

However, when I go to launch hive I get the following error message:

"Cannot find hadoop installation: $HADOOP_HOME or $HADOOP_PREFIX must be set or hadoop must be in the path"

My bashrc file reads this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin/


export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin


export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/hive
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/lib/*:.
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/hive/lib/*:.

export DERBY_HOME=/usr/local/derby
export PATH=$PATH:$DERBY_HOME/bin
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this? I presume it's an issue with how I have linked my Hadoop and hive,

Thanks in advance,

Maeve

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add HADOOP_HOME in hive-config.sh file.

```
user@ubuntu:~$ cd  /usr/local/hive/bin
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo gedit hive-config.sh
```

Go to the line where following statements are written in file:

```
HIVE_CONF_DIR="${HIVE_CONF_DIR:-$HIVE_HOME/conf"
export HIVE_CONF_DIR=$HIVE_CONF_DIR
export HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH=$HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH
```

Below this write the following

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1
```

Comment: ah yes, the path was wrong in that file! thanks very much

Answer (score 3):

Need to setup correct HADOOP_HOME on conf/hive-env.sh file as mentioned below

```
# Set HADOOP_HOME to point to a specific hadoop install directory
 HADOOP_HOME={your hadoop home location}
#e.g. as below
 HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop-2.6.0
```